# PHP/mySQL query to select date("N") plus 1 day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following PHP script:

```
$day = date("N");
$query_board = "SELECT day, time, timefromto, type, event, title, location, description, `until`, endtime FROM schedule WHERE `until` >= '$server_time' AND day LIKE '%$day%' ORDER BY `time` ASC";
```

This displays like so at [whatsondv.co.uk](http://whatsondv.co.uk):
[image: page image]

I want to create another page that will display results from the following day (i.e. tomorrow). So if the day were `2` (Tuesday), it would only take results where `3` appeared in `day`.

Would this require changing the definition of `$day` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prepared statement for this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $database . ';host=' . $host, $user, $password);
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT day, time, timefromto, type, event, title, location, description, `until`, endtime FROM schedule WHERE `until` >= :server_time AND day LIKE :day ORDER BY `time` ASC')
$query->execute(
  array(
    ':server_time' => $server_time,
    ':day' => $day
  )
);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Will this select anything greater than the current day? If so, how would you limit it to only selecting the next integer?

Comment: @Elliot How to you define the day / untill at the inserting of the events or how you want to name them?

Comment: Until is an hh:mm value

Answer (score 0):

Easier way round this: add another column that lists the 'day' value minus 1 (or in the case of 7, back to 1). Then use:

```
$day = date("N");
$query_board = "SELECT tmrw, time, timefromto, type, event, title, location, description, `until`, endtime FROM schedule WHERE `until` >= '$server_time' AND tmrw LIKE '%$day%' ORDER BY `time` ASC";
```

And that works.